# using a loop to input arraylist value into checkbox, gives wrong value

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

I have a form I would like to fill out with the following code. The purpose is to fill out the CheckBoxes, which are placed inside panels, and then placed in some TabPages. This code worked well to grab the value of the CheckBoxes, but for some reason it reads my ArrayList wrong. For example, if the ArrayList is filled with "1, 1, 0, 0, 0..." it will read every row as "1" and set the CheckBoxes accordingly.

I also tried placing an integer to see if it repeated the process multiple times (the ArrayList contains 16 rows) and the integer turned out to be several times the 16 rows. I did try to restrain the loop with an if sentence, and even though it stopped after a given number, it still produces the wrong answers.

I've come to a stop, and can't figure out why this code won't do the trick. Help would be greatly appreciated.

I should probably mention that 'tabell' is the ArrayList which I try to pull the data out of.

(Also, if this has been asked before, I am sincerely sorry for repeating the question..)

```
For Each rad In tabell
        For Each tb In TabControl1.Controls.OfType(Of TabPage)()
            For Each pnl In tb.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)().OrderBy(Function(c) c.TabIndex)
                For Each cb In pnl.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
                        If rad = 1 Then
                            cb.Checked = True
                        End If
                Next
            Next
            Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through all of the checkboxes for each value in `tabel1`, and since you never uncheck the boxes, the first `1` value will check all the boxes and that is how they will stay.

I am guessing that you want to use the corresponding value from `tabel1` based on the order that the checkboxes are found (which I think does not necessarily have to match the order that they appear on the screen, so you may have to sort the checkboxes too):

```
Dim idx = 0
For Each tb In TabControl1.Controls.OfType(Of TabPage)()
    For Each pnl In tb.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)().OrderBy(Function(c) c.TabIndex)
        For Each cb In pnl.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
            cb.Checked = tabel1(idx) = 1
            idx += 1
        Next
    Next
Next
```